# Enhancing MySQL Stored Procedure performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance, stored-procedures

i want to enhance performance of following Mysql Stored Procedure.

i am trying to XML with 100 items. and it is Taking almost 90 seconds. and Its too much.

Please check my following SP.

```
   DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `kshitij`.`Insert_date` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Insert_date`()
BEGIN

DECLARE itemstart   INTEGER default 1;
DECLARE valuestart  INTEGER default 1;
DECLARE itemcount   INTEGER;
DECLARE valuecount  INTEGER;

SET @xml = '<items>
    <size>2</size>
    <item>
        <value columntype="0" columnid="23">Single Line Text_0</value>
        <value columntype="1" columnid="24">Multi Line Text_0</value>
        <value columntype="2" columnid="25">Number_0</value>
        <value columntype="3" columnid="26">Link_0</value>
        <value columntype="4" columnid="27">Image_0</value>
        <value columntype="5" columnid="28">Date time_0</value>
    </item>
    TRYING WITH 100 ITEMS.
</items>';

SET itemcount = (SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, 'count(//item)'));
WHILE itemstart < itemcount
DO
  SET valuecount = (SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, 'count(/items/item[itemstart]/value)'));
  SET valuestart = 1;
  WHILE valuestart < valuecount
  DO
  IF((SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columntype')) = '0') THEN
    INSERT INTO singleline_text(value) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]'));
    INSERT INTO sheet_items(c_id, value_id) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columnid'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM singleline_text));
  END IF;

  IF((SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columntype')) = '1') THEN
    INSERT INTO multiline_text(value) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]'));
    INSERT INTO sheet_items(c_id, value_id) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columnid'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM multiline_text));
  END IF;

  IF((SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columntype')) = '2') THEN
    INSERT INTO number(value) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]'));
    INSERT INTO sheet_items(c_id, value_id) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columnid'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM number));
  END IF;

  IF((SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columntype')) = '3') THEN
    INSERT INTO link(value) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]'));
    INSERT INTO sheet_items(c_id, value_id) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columnid'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM link));
  END IF;

  IF((SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columntype')) = '4') THEN
    INSERT INTO image(value) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]'));
    INSERT INTO sheet_items(c_id, value_id) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columnid'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM image));
  END IF;

  IF((SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columntype')) = '5') THEN
    INSERT INTO date_time(value) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]'));
    INSERT INTO sheet_items(c_id, value_id) VALUES(ExtractValue(@xml, '/items/item[$itemstart]/value[$valuestart]/@columnid'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM date_time));
  END IF;
  SET valuestart = valuestart + 1;
END WHILE;
SET itemstart = itemstart + 1;
end while;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the declaration of the `ExtractValue` function as well. Besides, SQL is not the best tool to generate or parse XML, please give us a general description of what you are trying to achieve, there must be an alternative approach.

Comment: declare a variable, and execute the ExtractValue only once per loop...

Comment: @RandomSeed ExractValue is not my own Function. it's belongs to MySQL.check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html.

Comment: @SQL.injection i have already another way do this without performance problem. but i want to know why this type of big problem in mysql. this same thing i can do in just 2 to 3 seconds in oracle or MSSql Server.

Comment: I didn't know such functions existed, thank you for this new piece of info! I see values in your XPath expressions that seem to be invalid(eg. `$itemstart`). Are you building the function on the fly from an external language? Anyways, please remove all `INSERT` statements from your procedure, and compare its exeuction time.

Comment: yes. i did. extracting values from XML is taking too much time. and nothing i can do about that. anyway thanks for reply.